# Extra right margin on chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I am a bit confused with this. If I view the website as is, It appears to fit the screen properly. It fits when I click "inspect". It also fits still when I toggle "device mode".

However if I attempt to re-size or view different screen sizes in device mode, there is white space on the right at all sizes. It only does this with http://toqueholistico.com/.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

EDIT: screeonshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `.vc_row` class. It's applying a negative margin on the left and right, which is causing an overflow overall.

Try overriding it with:

```
.vc_row {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This did not fix it. It is weird because the extra space does not appear right away. I can adjust the responsive width and it's still ok for the first few seconds, then if I select a predetermined size in the responsive mode, or adjust it to quickly the space shows up and never goes away again after that. If I hover over the body element, the white space is not selected...

Comment: @CZorio I added the above rule via the Inspector in Chrome and it doesn't scroll horizontally at all: See http://i.imgur.com/kCPzhwA.png

When you view the applied rules in DevTools does the rule above get overridden by something else?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Check the screenshot I added to the original question . As you can see I added what you suggested and the gap is still there for the relevant row, and the the problem seems larger than that...the slider at the top is not confined in a vc row anyway. There is only one element that can be selected on my screen that will highlight the entire page width including that extra space...and it is not the body, html or the .container....it's the <header>.

Answer (score 0):

This questions helped me with a very similar issue with Bootstrap, also in Chrome (Version 66.0.3359.139). Right margin was particularly problematic on smaller viewports. I solved it by using:

```
  .row {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```